# Windows Service cannot access Castle Windsor config data in app.config

Tags: .net, configuration, castle-windsor, app-config

I use Castle Windsor in a couple of web apps just fine by putting the config data in web.config.

So when I decided to use it in a Windows Service I thought it would be a cinch. My app.config file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
  ...various other stuff...
  <castle>
    <components>
      ...component listings...
    </components>
  </castle>
</configuration>
```

I'm creating my container like this:

```
WindsorContainer windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
```

But crazily, when the app runs I get

```
Could not find section 'castle' in the configuration file associated with this domain.
   at Castle.Core.Resource.ConfigResource..ctor(String sectionName)
   at Castle.Core.Resource.ConfigResource..ctor()
   at Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters.AbstractInterpreter..ctor()
   at Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters.XmlInterpreter..ctor()
   ...application stack trace...
```

I'm a bit bamboozled. Anyone got any tips?

Cheers

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall something about app.config files and windows services.  Since the application that is actually "running" your service is svchost.exe and that exe exists in %windir%\system32, that is where you config file needs to be.  Try placing it there (%windir%\system32) and see what happens.

Comment: The app reads other config data out of app.config just fine but it's possible that Castle is looking in the location you mention. I'll check it out and have a look.

Comment: I've got another error now, lol! I think that means your suggestion worked. You have answered my question, but this is not acceptable to me as a workaround so I'm going to look into alternative configuration options.

Comment: I solved this problem by passing the location of the windsor configuration file to the XmlInterpreter's constructor (see code in question).

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's hit the obvious.  An executable will be using `myprog.exe.config` for it's configuration.  The app.config should be copied to that filename and placed in the output folder with the .exe.  Do you have that file with the service executable?

Comment: Why is there a minimum character limit on comments?! This site is mental.

Comment: does the file have the castle section (the one in output directory where you run your service from). You may hit some odd merge issues...

Comment: @Krzysztof: do you mean have I included the castle section in the app.config file? If so yes. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean the resulting file in the output directory. Can you make sure that it does have the section?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the windows service cannot access config data or sections not find what worked for me was created the container in this way:
new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")))